# How to prevent text from span to go under content from sibling span?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css-tables

I have two `span` elements next to each other. The first `span` has the symbol element, the second has the text. The text is too long and wraps under the symbol. Is there a way to keep text from going under the first `span`? Here is an example:

```css
table.tbl {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}

table.tbl thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table.tbl tbody td {
  text-align: left;
}

span.symbol {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="symbol">?</span>
        <span class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.</span>
        <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to prevent text to go under the symbol span?

That should look like this:

```
?  Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will 
   wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.    
   - Test User Name 02/07/2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the HTML, you could set the spans to be `display:table-cell;`. EG:

```
span.symbol, span.text {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

This way they will sit beside each other like so:

```css
table.tbl {
 font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}
table.tbl thead th {
 text-align: left;
}
table.tbl tbody td {
 text-align: left;
}
span.symbol {
 color: red;
 font-weight: bold;
}
span.symbol, span.text {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td>Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="symbol">?</span>
    <span class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.</span>
    <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, really you should be wrapping the two blocks of content in elements that you can control more easily.

```css
table.tbl {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}

table.tbl thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table.tbl tbody td {
  text-align: left;
}

.symbol {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.symbol,
.text {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="symbol">?</div>
        <div class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.
          <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="symbol">?</div>
        <div class="text">Here we have some text that is short.
          <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since you're using a table anyway why not just have a nested table or more cells and colspans? EG:

```css
table.tbl {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}

table.tbl thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table.tbl tbody td {
  text-align: left;
}

td.symbol {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="symbol">?</td>
        <td class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.
          <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="symbol">?</td>
        <td class="text">Here we have some that is short.
          <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text content into a div element(`text-wrap` in below code), and also everything inside the `td` into a div element (`wrap` element) and make it a *flexbox* - see demo below:

```css
table.tbl {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}

table.tbl thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table.tbl tbody td {
  text-align: left;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

span.symbol {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="symbol">?</span>
          <div class="text-wrap">
            <span class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.</span>
            <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A non-flexbox solution using *tables* using the same markup as above:

```css
table.tbl {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}

table.tbl thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table.tbl tbody td {
  text-align: left;
}

span.symbol {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrap {
  display: table;
}

.wrap>* {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="wrap">
          <span class="symbol">?</span>
          <div class="text-wrap">
            <span class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.</span>
            <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a problem since flex box is not supported in IE. One of the requirements in my project is to support IE (version 9 and up). Is there a way to achieve this with plain css?

Answer (score 1):

make the symbol `float` element and make the height bigger enough:

```css
table.tbl {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 500px;
}

table.tbl thead th {
  text-align: left;
}

table.tbl tbody td {
  text-align: left;
}

span.symbol {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data Validation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Form validation text description and some instructions.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="symbol">?</span>
        <span class="text">Here we have some text that can be too long sometimes. In that case text will wrap under question mark symbol from the span element above.</span>
        <br><span style="color:red">- Test User Name 02/07/2019</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works but has the problem/feature of forcing the `.symbol` to always be at least 50px high (even if the `.text` is short). Additionally if the text is VERY long that 50px padding may not be enough.